# I don't want the smallest one, I want the second-smallest one

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, computer-puzzle

Inspired by my struggles with a certain open-source online learning platform's grading system:

You are working in a computer language with a limited set of built-in functions.  You have a set of $m$ real numbers $x_1, x_2, \dots x_m$.  These numbers are in some arbitrary, unknown order (i.e., they do not necessarily monotonically increase or decrease.)

You wish to write a function that returns the "second-smallest" of these numbers, where duplicate entries are treated as distinct.  In other words, if we were to list the numbers from smallest to largest, this function would return the second number in that ordered list.  For example, if the numbers are $\{ 2, 6, 1, 7\}$, the function should return $2$.  If the numbers are $\{ 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5 \}$, the function should return $4$.

The functions that are you can use are:

- `max(x1, x2, ...)` and `min(x1, x2, ...)`:  Accepts any number of real-number arguments. Returns the largest one or the smallest one, respectively.
- `sum(x1, x2, ...)`:  Accepts any number of real-number arguments.  Returns the sum of all of them.

In addition, you may use the standard arithmetic operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `^`.

#### BONUS QUESTION:

Extend your method to return the $n$th smallest number among the set.

*My intended answers for both questions use only `max`, `sum`, and arithmetic operations.  However, if you can come up with a more elegant answer that uses other built-in functions [on this list,](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Grade_calculations#Calculation_functions) it would also be of interest to me.  :-)*

Comment: *If the numbers are {4,5,4,4,4,5}, the function should return 4* Shouldn't the function return 5 here, since 4 is the smallest number?

Comment: From my understanding, duplicates seem to count, so the ordered list would be {4,4,4,4,5,5} not {4,5}

Comment: @Oliver I guess the question somewhat contradicts itself, as it asks for the second smallest number (indicating that it should be greater than the smallest), and then it asks for the second number in an ordered list.

Comment: @kaitlynmm569:  Oliver's understanding is correct.  I'll try to edit this to make it clearer.

Comment: Dear @Michael Seifert, does the intended solution for 2nd-in-order use
$O(m^2)$ instances of $x_i$ as in the two answers so far, whose numbers of
instances are $m^2\!{-}m$ and $m^2$?

Comment: The answer to this question will be useful for this purpose: [YouTube video for Second Cheapest Wine](https://youtu.be/mlg3H1StHpQ)

Comment: Do you know the value of $m$ before writing the program?

Comment: @humn:  Yes, the solution I came up with uses $O(m^2)$ instances of each $x_i$.

Comment: @melfnt:  Yes, you can assume that $m$ is known when you write the function.  However, you should describe how the program would be written for an arbitrary value of $m$ (if that makes sense.)

Comment: Does your language allow assigning variables and iterating through a list? Or does it allow (tail-) recursion?

Comment: This is might be what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I think it's different. This question asks for a _branchless_ expression (i.e., no conditionals). While the methods in selection algorithm uses series of instructions to find it, where the next instruction to execute depends on the result of the previous one.

Comment: "In addition, you may use the standard arithmetic operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `^`." Is `^` exponentiation or bitwise xor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best I can come up is this:

> $$min((x_1+x_2),(x_1+x_3),\cdots,(x_{m-1}+x_m)) - min(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)$$

i.e.

> Finding the minimum sum of two numbers, then subtract it with the smallest one.

So for the $n$-th smallest:

> Try to find the minimum sum of $n$ numbers, then subtract it with the minimum sum of $n-1$ numbers.

Comment: The problem is that the construction of the list of sums of pairs is an operation... This will be obvious if one thinks about a real implementation (i.e. writing down a piece of code that works). Namely, one should write down a formula without the $\cdots$ symbol. Of course the issue already exists in the question itself.

Answer (score 19):

Maybe I don't get it (I mean, it is a solution, I just don't know if it is allowed), but:

> $max(min(set_1)min(set_2)…min(set_m))$ where each $set_k$ contains all numbers, except $x_k$ (and number of sets equals $(m)$ )

and for $3$rd smallest number it would be similar

> just each "set" would contain all numbers except two - and every combination of that, so number of sets would be something like $(m)$x$(m-1)/2$.

and for $4$th smallest number it would be similar

> just each "set" would contain all numbers except three - and every combination of that, so number of sets would be something like $(m)$x$(m-1)$x$(m-2)/(3!)$.
>  Divided by 3! because I just take one combination of certain $x_i$, $x_j$, $x_k$, and ignoring ($x_j$, $x_i$, $x_k$), ($x_k$, $x_i$, $x_j$), ($x_j$, $x_k$, $x_i$), ($x_k$, $x_j$, $x_i$), ($x_i$, $x_k$, $x_j$).

and so on

Comment: This is a good variation of answer! Doesn't use any operator, only max and min. So depending on whether the operation or function is more expensive, we can choose to use either this or athin's answer.

Comment: This answer hadn't occurred to me.  Cool!

Answer (score 9):

> This solution was originally inspired by [athin's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101382), but with an improved way of generating the sum of the two smallest numbers. Now, it is a variant on [Bass's solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101433) since, as suggested by them in the comments, we can change the sum to a max, and then we don't need to subtract the smallest number at the end.

> Let's index the inputs as $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{m-1}$. Write the numbers $0, 1, \dots, m-1$ in binary. For each $k=1,2,\dots,\lceil\log_2 m\rceil$, let $A_k$ be the min of all $x_i$ such that $i$ has a $0$ in the $k$-th position; let $B_k$ be the min of all $x_i$ such that $i$ has a $1$ in the $k$-th position. Then our solution is $$\min(\max(A_1,B_1),\max(A_2,B_2),\dots,\max(A_k,B_k)).$$ The number of $x$'s in this expression is $m \lceil \log_2 m \rceil$.

Here's why this works:

> Each $\max(A_k,B_k)$ will be the max of two elements, so it's at least the second-smallest element. On the other hand, if $x_i$ and $x_j$ are the two smallest $x$'s, then there has to be some position $k$ where the binary representations of $i$ and $j$ differ; say, $i$ has a $0$ in the $k$-th position, and $j$ has a $1$. Then we'll get $A_k = x_i$ and $B_k = x_j$, so $\max(A_k,B_k) = \max(x_i,x_j)$ will definitely show up in the min we take. No other $\max(A_{k'}, B_{k'})$ can be smaller, so $\max(x_i,x_j)$, the second-smallest element, is our final answer.

Here's an example of the finished formula for $m=8$:

> $$\min\Big(\max(\min(x_0,x_2,x_4,x_6),\min(x_1,x_3,x_5,x_7)), \max(\min(x_0,x_1,x_4,x_5),\min(x_2,x_3,x_6,x_7)), \max(\min(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3),\min(x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7))\Big).$$

And here is a diagram of that solution drawn by [humn](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18129/humn):

> [image: diagram]

---

We can sort of generalize this to an $O(m \log m)$ solution for finding the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest element, by relying on a [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3403465/383078) answer written a year ago by a clever and handsome individual.

I say "sort of" because this is only a random construction. Not in the sense that it works only on some random inputs. It's random in the sense that I'll describe a method for generating a formula with some randomness in the method; with positive probability, it'll give us a formula that always works for all inputs.

Here's how.

> A "clause" in our formula looks like the following. We split $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ into $k$ sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k$, and then take $$\max\{\min\{x_i : i \in S_1\}, \min\{x_i : i \in S_2\}, \dots, \min\{x_i : i \in S_k\}\}.$$ The value this generates is always a max of $k$ distinct elements, so it's *at least* the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest. And if the $k$ smallest elements happen to be distributed evenly between $S_1, \dots, S_k$, then the value of the clause *is* the $k^{\text{th}}$ smallest element.

> To make sure this always happens, we generate many clauses at random: for each $i \in \{1,2,\dots,m\}$, we  choose (independently and uniformly at random) to put it in one of $S_1, \dots, S_k$. As shown in the Math.SE answer I linked to, if we generate $\frac{k^k}{k!} \ln \binom mk \approx k e^k \ln m$ clauses, then with positive probability it will be true that for *any* $k$ variables, there's a clause that separates them. When this happens, our final formula will be the min of all these clauses.

Comment: The reasoning doesn't work if the two smallest elements are the same, right? 2ndMin(4,4,4,5,5) should be 4, not 5. (I haven't checked whether your solution as a whole has this correct, but the reasoning at least is faulty)

Comment: @justhalf Oh, I see what you were confused by now. There was a (partial) typo in the reasoning; we never compare $x_i$ to $x_j$ to see where they differ, we only compare $i$ and $j$ to see where they differ (and they always will, even if the two smallest elements are the same).

Comment: $\sim m\log m$ is fantastic!

Comment: Ah, right, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarification! And, great algorithm!

Comment: I wonder whether this can be generalized to n-th smallest element. The main challenge is to find the list of partitioning into three partitions that guarantee that all possible triplets appear in distinct partitions in at least one partitioning. Misha has found the list of partitioning into two partitions in this answer. But it's not trivial to find the similar one for 3 elements.

Comment: If you replace every addition with a two-argument max(), you can skip the final subtraction.

Comment: @Bass Thanks! Improved (with attribution).

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I think you need to update your first sentence too with the change to max. (And when I noticed who wrote the Math.SE answer now I understand who you were referring to by awesome and handsome individual). I think the terminology used should not be "with positive probability" (both here and in your Math.SE answer), since 0.00000001 is also a positive probability, but we don't want that to be our probability of success. Perhaps you mean "with probability 1-$\varepsilon$"? That is, we can make it as close to 1 as possible, with a configurable error rate.

Comment: @justhalf In this case, "with positive probability" is enough. As long as, with positive probability, we generate a formula that works, then that means there exists a formula that works. After that, we can use the formula with no error rate at all. If you want, we can say that we find the formula by brute force over all possible clauses - the probabilistic proof just gives us a number of clauses that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I meant, "with positive probability" does not usually mean "the number of clauses that is guaranteed to work". If you want to say that, usually we say "with probability 1-$\varepsilon$" or "with probability 1" is it's dense.

Comment: You're missing the point. If there is a positive probability that a random set of $\frac{k^k}{k!} \ln \binom mk$ clauses works, then in particular there is *some* set of $\frac{k^k}{k!} \ln \binom mk$ that works - otherwise, the probability would be $0$. Then, we just pick the set of clauses that works.

Comment: @humn It's a very nice diagram, thank you!

Comment: Thank _you_ for adding to my understanding of hypercubes, @Misha Lavrov.
Seeing the diagram in place made me realize that
it didn't italicize $A_k$ and $B_k$, now corrected.
By the way, i also very much appreciate how
your extension to finding the $k^{\text{th}}$ of $m$ elements
takes advantage of the bonanza of orthogonal subsets in hyperdimensions.

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another approach. It kind of sits between [@athin's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101382/36023) and [@Jan Ivan's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/101380/36023) methods.

It's based on the observation that the second smallest number is

> the smallest number that is bigger than (or equal to) some other number.

This means we can do

> a min() over all the possible pairwise max()es:
>  $$\min\left(\max(x_1, x_2), \max(x_1,x_3),\ldots, \max(x_{m-1}, x_m)\right)$$

To double check that this works, we only have to notice that

> the smallest number will never show up as one of the max()es, unless there's a tie for the smallest, which is exactly the special case when we *do* want it to show up.